# Seeking open source tools to visualize map projection distortion?

Tags: coordinate-system, software-recommendations, open-source-gis, visualisation

A reference article on [Map Projections](https://gistbok.ucgis.org/bok-topics/map-projections) contains the following figure:

[image]

I think the images are created using [Geocart](https://www.mapthematics.com/Index.php), listed in Additional Resources section. I'm interested in trying to create visualizations like this--particularly the areal distortion and angular distortion visualizations--using open source tools. Either desktop GIS or code (Python, R, etc.) would be helpful.

Comment: You could use the coordinate system and open source GIS tags together to come up with some candidates to test. Asking the community to come up with a list of candidates for you is what makes this too broad. Once you are testing a candidate and get stuck you will have a question suitable for focused Q&A.